# CSS - Using attr() function without ::before and ::after

Tags: css, sass, less

I want to use`attr()`function in some span, but I won't use ::after and ::before pseudo-elements. For example:

```
<span size="36">Text</span>
<style>
    span[size]{
        font-size: attr(size pt);
    }
</style>
```

Is it possible to do so using CSS or SASS or LESS?

Comment: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than `content` is experimental.

Comment: It is only experimental for any property other than `content`, [cf. MDN attr() in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

Comment: What means "Experimental"? Is it working in Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: No. There is not support for `attr()` in other properties than `content` and non-string values: http://caniuse.com/#search=attr()

Comment: What you want are [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) ?

Comment: "Experimental" doesn't actually mean anything here. Dekel and Vivick probably meant to say "nonexistent". There *is no* support for level 3 attr() whatsoever.

Comment: @zer00ne: No, the asker definitely means attr(). Two different things.

Comment: @zer00ne: Actually, that might make for an interesting Q&A.

Comment: @BoltClock I know, I was suggesting perhaps another means to his objective, but I wasn't totally sure what `(size pt)` was supposed be.

Comment: @zer00ne: It's the value of the size attribute from the markup, in points. (Cue "just use span style=...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) returns a `string` and as such the only property it will practically work on as of today is the `content` property.

In your case it will return the *string* `36` and will therefore not be properly applied.

Its syntax has an experimental second parameter, [`<type-or-unit>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Syntax), where one amongst other should be able to choose the returned value's data type, though no browser support it yet.

---

A side note, both SASS and LESS *compiles* into CSS and aren't able extend the CSS into something CSS can't already do.